# GraphQL : Using Relay without having to use edges & node

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

I've successfully built a GraphQL based API using Graphene-Django.  In doing this, I used Relay.

My front-end colleagues are annoyed with having to specify "edges & node" and then pull out the data they want from the similar looking response.

Is there a way to use Relay without "edges & node"?

Robert

Answer (score 1):

Edges and node are part of specification of the pagination.
If you don't need pagination, you can use simple lists(graphene.List) without edges and node

see:
[documentation](http://graphql.org/learn/pagination/)